# Java Reflection to map Properties to Object

Tags: java, dictionary, reflection, properties, mapping

i got the following source code to map the properties file to my Object.

```
    private Configuration MapPropertiesToObjectOrNull(Properties defaultProps){

    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    Enumeration e = defaultProps.propertyNames();

    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) e.nextElement();
        try {
            Field currField = config.getClass().getDeclaredField(key);
            try {
                currField.set(config, defaultProps.getProperty(key) );
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return config;

}
```

Is this a good "mapping approach" to avoid hardcoded "Key"-String in my source code? You maybe have some other ideas?

Comment: You wanted to handle dynamic keys, is it ?

Comment: The Propertynames in Class and Propertyfile have to be equivalent. I do not think theres a possibility to do it dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

You are making things complicated, as in general, in Java/J2EE applications, we assume that the KEYS are constants and values can be modified at later, so we create properties files (like for example to store database username, password, we come up with keys like USER_NAME, PASSWORD, etc.., which never change, where as the values can be modified, if want).

To simply read key and values from properties files, you can use the below code snippet:

```
   try {
       File file = new File("test.properties");
       FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.load(fileInput);

       Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
        while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
           String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
           String value = properties.getProperty(key);
           System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
           //you can load here to HashMap which can be retrived later
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
           fileInput.close();
      }
```

Comment: Yes, but now I have Strings in my source code. If I use `prop.getProperty("foo");` 5 times in project, and I change the key, I have to change it 5 times. With my solution I hope, i just can refactor class propertyname and everything is fine. and I can ignore not used or wrong keys from file (at my function; not done yet)

Comment: As I mentioned, we generally assume that the keys are STATIC, but they do not change, but the other alternative is declare it as PUBLIC STATIC FINAL String in a "Keys.java" file, so you can change it from only one place.

Comment: The public static final idea is not bad.

Comment: If you take my example again, the key is USERNAME, do you think that this     will change ? At least 99% of the times, you assume the KEY as constant, but the associated values can change at any time.

Comment: Yes, if in rare case if the key changes you need to update the class files.

Comment: "in Java/J2EE applications, we assume that the KEYS are constants" - wat?